# Loss of size of numbers when processing in hex format

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numbers, hex

Faced a problem while processing hex numbers.
When running `str (hex ())` from a file, the zeros after `0x...` disappear.

*At the entrance:*

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f01f80f12f7cf16638f7a8074d46fe2f421a73432b1441a01ed3dd883c68acad
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000029a799033fc54073346f870c15c9836f6b2e9eccdb85f09d29a8ddc90dc3a8ef1
0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000033e561483073e429ec25c09c99de2a81d5a34a539ad2dbb688af6b6f5f24936a4
```

On exit:

```
0x1f01f80f12f7cf16638f7a8074d46fe2f421a73432b1441a01ed3dd883c68acad
0x29a799033fc54073346f870c15c9836f6b2e9eccdb85f09d29a8ddc90dc3a8ef1
0x33e561483073e429ec25c09c99de2a81d5a34a539ad2dbb688af6b6f5f24936a4
```

Code:

```
   with open("data.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            L = int(line, 0)
            R = str(hex(L))
            print(R)
```

What needs to be fixed in the code? I need one size of numbers and no loss of zeros.

Comment: can you please provide your code?

Comment: you're probably looking for string formatting to pad the value

Comment: @0dminnimda  Wrote the code

Comment: `hex(L)` returns a string so `str(hex(L))` is redundant.

Comment: @ti7 I need it to be one size

Comment: when you say _size_, do you mean _string length_? what length should they be? (the starting strings appear to be 130)

Comment: @Mark Tolonen
 When I do `print(L)` the numbers are displayed in decimal format, although in the text file data.txt all numbers are in HEX format

Comment: @DewDebra `R = hex(L)` is the same thing as `R = str(hex(L))`.  `hex()` returns a string.  `L` isn't a string.  Print `R`.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen  Then how to take numbers from files so that they do not change during processing `for line in file:` ?

Comment: Lines are read as strings.  Just don't convert them to integers and they print exactly as read.  If you convert them into an integer, the *default* printing of an integer is decimal.  If you don't want that, use string formatting as in my answer when displaying the integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string formatting:

- `#` means put `0x` on the front for hex numbers.
- `0130` means the fields is 130 characters long, the leading zero means pad with zeros.
- `x` means hexadecimal (lowercase a-f).

```py
line = '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f01f80f12f7cf16638f7a8074d46fe2f421a73432b1441a01ed3dd883c68acad'
print(line)  # as read from file
integer = int(line, 0)
formatted = f'{integer:#0130x}'
print(formatted)
print(formatted == line) # check that original and re-formatted are the same
```

Output:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f01f80f12f7cf16638f7a8074d46fe2f421a73432b1441a01ed3dd883c68acad
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f01f80f12f7cf16638f7a8074d46fe2f421a73432b1441a01ed3dd883c68acad
True
```